# Why does read.csv2 work just fine, yet read.csv2.sql shows an error/warning?

Tags: r, csv, sqldf

I am trying to read a csv file in R using `read.csv2.sql`, since I would like to use a `SELECT` query from SQL to help me filter my data, but before I can even get to my `SELECT` query, I discovered that simply reading my csv file using `read.csv2.sql` already generates a warning message.

This is my code:

```
investment2 <- read.csv2.sql("investmentdata.csv")
```

This is the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  Column 'Capital.Investment': mixed type, first seen values of type real, coercing other values of type string
```

However, when I use the normal `read.csv2` function, there is no error. In particular, the following code works fine with no warning messages:

```
investment <- read.csv2("investmentdata.csv")
```

Next, I tried to resolve this issue by casting the `Capital.Investment` column to be real as follows:

```
investment3 <- read.csv2.sql("investmentdata.csv", "SELECT *, CAST(Capital.Investment AS real) FROM file")
```

However, R now generates the following error:

```
Error: no such column: Capital.Investment
```

Thus, I have two questions. Firstly, why does using `read.csv2.sql` generate that warning message when `read.csv2` works just fine? Secondly, why does R (or SQL) not recognise my `Capital.Investment` column when I try to cast it as real?

Perhaps it is also worth noting that I cannot simply ignore this warning that the `read.csv2.sql` function is showing, because I discovered that as a consequence of this warning, it has automatically casted some of the `NA` rows in my `Capital.Investment` column to `0`, which I cannot allow - the `NA` rows must stay as `NA`. I do not seem to be having this problem with the other columns of my csv file though.

As I am quite new to R, any help and explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit**

The coded version of what my truncated csv file looks like is as follows. In particular, the name of the column-in-question is indeed `Capital.Investment`.

```
id;targetC;year;comp_id;homeC;Industry.Activity;Capital.Investment;Estimated;Jobs.Created;Estimated.1;Project.Type;geographic distance;SIC;listed;sales;assets;cap_structure;rnd;profit;rndintensity;polcon;homeC_gdp;targetC_gdp;homeC_gdppc;targetC_gdppc
1302;AUS;2008;FR338966385;FRA;Design, Development & Testing;33.1;Yes;36;Yes;New;15.26414042;3669;Unlisted;4333088.972;4037211.732;0;NA;-1339221.733;NA;0.489032525;2.92347E+12;1.05456E+12;45413.06571;49628.11513
1311;AUS;2008;US*190521496652;USA;Research & Development;8.4;Yes;30;No;New;15.24712914;NA;Unlisted;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
1313;AUS;2008;GB05817296;GBR;Business Services;9.7;Yes;10;Yes;New;15.31094496;7389;Unlisted;NA;87.64187374;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;2.87546E+12;1.05456E+12;46523.26545;49628.11513
1318;AUS;2008;US129687150L;USA;Business Services;1.3;Yes;225;Yes;New;15.24712914;7373;Unlisted;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
1351;AUS;2008;GB*P0060071;GBR;Electricity;516;No;51;Yes;New;15.31094496;NA;Unlisted;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;2.87546E+12;1.05456E+12;46523.26545;49628.11513
9925;AUS;2008;GB00034121;GBR;Business Services;34.8;Yes;37;Yes;New;15.31094496;4412;Unlisted;NA;2079288.611;0.355157008;NA;94320.15469;NA;0.489032525;2.87546E+12;1.05456E+12;46523.26545;49628.11513
9932;AUS;2008;CA30060NC;CAN;Sales, Marketing & Support;3.2;Yes;11;Yes;New;14.88812529;1094;Listed;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.54913E+12;1.05456E+12;46596.33599;49628.11513
9935;AUS;2008;US940890210;USA;Manufacturing;771;Yes;266;Yes;New;15.24712914;2911;Listed;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
9938;AUS;2008;US770059951;USA;Technical Support Centre;9.1;Yes;104;Yes;Co-Locati;15.24712914;3661;Listed;34922000;53340000;0.120134983;4598000;7333000;0.086201723;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
9946;AUS;2008;US010562944;USA;Extraction;535.8;Yes;198;Yes;New;15.24712914;2911;Listed;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
9955;AUS;2008;DE5030147191;DEU;Logistics, Distribution & Transportation;21.2;Yes;134;Yes;New;14.6718338;4311;Listed;93495971.01;346629334.8;0.036629492;0;2044745.934;0;0.489032525;3.75237E+12;1.05456E+12;45699.19832;49628.11513
9958;AUS;2008;US126012192L;USA;Business Services;9.7;Yes;10;Yes;New;15.24712914;8111;Unlisted;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
9969;AUS;2008;US135409005;USA;Extraction;NA;No;538;Yes;New;15.24712914;2911;Listed;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
9977;AUS;2008;JP000000728JPN;JPN;ICT & Internet Infrastructure;128.6;Yes;77;Yes;New;7.0333688;3571;Listed;53255396.85;38181450.16;0.190244908;2584585.523;480589.4308;0.067692176;0.489032525;5.03791E+12;1.05456E+12;39339.29757;49628.11513
9984;AUS;2008;US841547578;USA;Sales, Marketing & Support;13.6;Yes;23;Yes;New;15.24712914;2095;Listed;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
9993;AUS;2008;US258715604L;USA;Customer Contact Centre;1.8;No;40;No;New;15.24712914;NA;Unlisted;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;0.489032525;1.47E+13;1.05456E+12;48401.42734;49628.11513
```

Comment: I'm going to guess, since we don't see your data: in SQL, `Capital.Investment` is likely seen as either `schema="Capital", table="Investment"` or `table="Capital", column="Investment"` (or something else) depending on context. If you replace it with either `cast([Capital.Investment] ...)` or `cast("Capital.Investment" ...)`, does it work?

Comment: @r2evans No... Neither works... Using `[Capital.Investment]` simply generates the same warning message as in my post, while using `"Capital.Investment"` generates the following error: `Error: unexpected symbol in "investment2 <- read.csv2.sql("investmsntdata.csv", "SELECT *, CAST("Capital.Investment"`. I am also not sure what you mean by the first part of your comment though... my data is from a csv file with `;` as delimiters and the column name is indeed `Capital.Investment`.

Comment: The "unexpected symbol" is because you need to either backslash-escape the inner quotes, as in `"select ... \"Capital.Investment\" ..."` or use single-quotes as the outer string delimiters, as in `'select ... "Capital.Investment" ...'`.

Comment: My answer works with *my* version of a CSV (or `;`-delimited, same thing) file, perhaps you can share the raw top-4 lines of *your* csv file in your question? It doesn't need all of the columns, just enough to demonstrate the error while allowing us to see the actual file contents.

Comment: (I meant in a form that we can use, as in within a code block. I'm not transcribing. However, the image of the data looks no different from my fake data, in concept/structure.)

Comment: @r2evans Sorry, I am not too well-versed with R... How do I produce "the raw top-4 lines" of my csv file in R? Wouldn't that be the first screenshot in my edit?

Comment: Two ways: (1) Not in R, edit it in `notepad` or some text editor, copy the first 4 or so lines, paste into a code-block here. (2) In R, run `writeLines(paste(readLines("investmentdata.csv", n=6), collapse="\n"), "clipboard")` and then paste directly into a code block here. If you're on macos, replace `"clipboard"` with `pipe("pbcopy", "w")`.

Comment: But the point is *not a screenshot*. Two main reasons: (1) if there are unicode or other nuances in the actual text, a screenshot may not show it; (2) I'm not spending time transcribing data, it's usually best to work with something as-representative-as-possible. The less-favored (but perhaps more-pure) solution would be to post your file (or the head of it) via pastebin.com or some other sharing mechanism. Not always popular, but it can work.)

Comment: @r2evans Okay, I have ran `writeLines(paste(readLines("investmentdata.csv", n=6), collapse="\n"), "clipboard")` in my RStudio, but I do not see any output?

Comment: Read my whole comment, please. I said *"run `writeLines(...)` **and then paste directly into a code block here**"* (in your original question). The `writeLines(..., "clipboard")` puts the contents directly into your clipboard, sight-unseen. Try to paste.

Comment: @r2evans oh, I see how it works now. Sorry about that. I have pasted what you asked for into my edit!

Comment: This isn't going to make you happen, but when I save those six lines of text into my `"quux.csv"` and run `read.csv2.sql("quux.csv", sql='select cast([Capital.Investment] as real) as CI from file')`, it works.

Comment: I should ask: is there a reason you must use `read.csv2.sql`? You could just read it in with `read.csv2` and use regular R functions for conversion (e.g., `investment3$Capital.Investment <- as.numeric(investment3$Capital.Investment)`).

Comment: @r2evans Hmm... I did a little further troubleshooting and indeed `read.csv2.sql` works fine for the first 110 lines of data. However, when I use `read.csv2.sql` to read the first 111 lines of data, that warning message pops up. I am very perplexed by this. Also, as mentioned above, I want to use `read.csv2.sql` because I want to make use of the `SELECT` query function - I actually just want to load a subset of my entire csv file. For example, say, I have data from Australia and New Zealand, but I only want to read the data from Australia. Would there be another way to do this?

Comment: I understand. Replace the current data with this: `writeLines(paste(readLines("investmentdata.csv", n=115)[c(1:6,105:115)], collapse="\n"), "clipboard")`, and I'll take a look. I'm curious to see what lines 110-112 look like.

Comment: (That's really good sleuthing, btw, I'm not surprised it's *one line of data* that could be mucking up the works here.)

Comment: @r2evans I have edited my post again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234920/discussion-between-r2evans-and-ethan-mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234920/discussion-between-r2evans-and-ethan-mark), to be one of two issues:

- see my original answer below, this was causing an `Error`; when that is fixed, we see that ...
- there is a *warning*, informing about the fact that a column (happens to be the same column) looks `numeric` but has a non-numeric cell somewhere within the guts of the file.

The first is resolved below, the second is just a warning.

**However**, because the OP is asking to convert to numeric via SQL, the `NA` is converted to `0`, which is not good. My recommendation is to either `cast([Capital.Investment] as char) as [Capital.Investment]` and use R's `as.numeric` to convert to numeric (preserving the `NA`-nature), or to just `read.csv2(.)` the file outright and use `sqldf(.)` to use its SQL querying on table-like data.

---

**Up front**: add brackets or quotes around your column name.

**Rationale**: `Capital.Investment` is seen as a dot-delimited table-column or schema-table or something similarly not what you intend. I believe in general in SQL that field names with embedded dots need this escaping. If your data has an embedded space, realize that R does not like spaces in its field names, so it is by-default using `make.names` when reading it in (which replaces spaces with dots).

Setup:

Save the following as `"quux.csv"`. (I've named it `csv`, but since I'm changing it to be `;`-delimited, it behaves the same.)

```
quux;Capital.Investment
1;100
2;200
```

(Or you can use `Capital Investment`, it's the same thing.)

```r
sqldf::read.csv2.sql("quux.csv", sql='select quux, cast(Capital.Investment as real) from file')
# Error: no such column: Capital.Investment
sqldf::read.csv2.sql("quux.csv", sql='select quux, cast([Capital.Investment] as real) as CI from file')
#   quux  CI
# 1    1 100
# 2    2 200
sqldf::read.csv2.sql("quux.csv", sql='select quux, cast("Capital.Investment" as real) as CI from file')
#   quux  CI
# 1    1 100
# 2    2 200
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!